# how to get the response data from a POST request using Express/Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I am new in Node/Express and I would like to get some help with the following situation. I want to create a function that will execute when calling an API endpoint which will return a list of addresses from another API that is already working. I was following some code I found in the tutorials and when calling the function in Postman as an endpoint, it returns the data in the terminal but I want the data to be return in postman.

```
getAddress() {
    let result=[];

    const address = JSON.stringify({
      number: "1234",
      street: "Main St",
      city: "Newark",
      state: "NJFL",
      zipCode: "01234",

    });

    const https = require("https");
    const options = {
      hostname: "thisiaurl",
      port: 8001,
      path: "/address",
      method: "POST",
      json: address,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);
        res.on("data", (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
      });
    });

    req.on("error", (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

    req.write(address);
    req.end();

    return result;
  };
```

I am not sure how to modify this code in order to return the "result" with the list of addresses (response). Can you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try

```
    result = address;
```

Before

```
    const https = require("https");
```

Line.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I actually need the response data. If I do your suggestion, I am getting the address object and not the list of addresses from the request.